# SQL Server 2012 compatibility error for =*

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

When I have migrated the SQL Server database into SQL Server 2012, I got compatibility issues for `=*` and I was said that it is used for right outer join and made code changes as follows

```
--OLD CODE
SELECT 
    EMPLOYEE_CODE 'EMPLOYEE CODE', MSKID 'MAERSKID',  
    isNull(FIRST_NAME,'') + ' ' + isNull(SECOND_NAME,'') +  ' ' + isNull(THIRD_NAME,'') 'FULL NAME', 
    LM.LOCATION_NAME 'LOCATION', CM.COMPANY_NAME 'COMPANY', 
    DEPT.ACTIVITY_NAME 'DEPARTMENT',LVL.LEVEL_NAME 'LEVEL', 
    CARD_NUMBER 'CARD NO'
FROM 
    smart2uat.dbo.EMPLOYEE_MAST EMP, smart2uat.dbo.ACTIVITY_MAST DEPT, 
    smart2uat.dbo.LEVEL_MAST LVL, smart2uat.dbo.LOCATION_MAST LM, 
    smart2uat.dbo.COMPANY_MAST CM
WHERE
    DEPT.ACTIVITY_CODE =* EMP.ACTIVITY_CODE AND 
    LVL.LEVEL_CODE =* EMP.LEVEL_CODE AND 
    LM.LOCATION_CODE =* EMP.LOCATION_CODE AND 
    CM.COMPANY_CODE =* EMP.COMPANY_CODE
```

and I've changed the code as

```
--NEW CODE IN SQL SERVER 2012
SELECT EMPLOYEE_CODE 'EMPLOYEE CODE', MSKID 'MAERSKID',  isNull(FIRST_NAME,'') + ' ' + isNull(SECOND_NAME,'') +  ' ' + isNull(THIRD_NAME,'') 'FULL NAME',    
    LM.LOCATION_NAME 'LOCATION', CM.COMPANY_NAME 'COMPANY', DEPT.ACTIVITY_NAME 'DEPARTMENT',  
    LVL.LEVEL_NAME 'LEVEL', CARD_NUMBER 'CARD NO' from
    smart2uat.dbo.ACTIVITY_MAST DEPT  right outer join  smart2uat.dbo.EMPLOYEE_MAST EMP  on DEPT.ACTIVITY_CODE = EMP.ACTIVITY_CODE ,
    smart2uat.dbo.LEVEL_MAST LVL right outer join EMP on LVL.LEVEL_CODE = EMP.LEVEL_CODE,
    smart2uat.dbo.LOCATION_MAST LM right outer join EMP on LM.LOCATION_CODE = EMP.LOCATION_CODE ,
    smart2uat.dbo.COMPANY_MAST CM right outer join EMP  on CM.COMPANY_CODE = EMP.COMPANY_CODE
```

I am not getting expected output as old code and new code throwing error. Is this transformation from old code to new code correct?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `and new code throwing error. ` and where is error message?

Comment: @lad2025..I actually donno whether this transormation is correct. And the error message is - 
      `Invalid object name 'EMP'`

Comment: I think your transformation is incorrect. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need all records from `EMPLOYEE_MAST` with `LEFT JOIN` to rest of tables. Also use `CONCAT` instead of `+` for strings.

```
SELECT
  [EMPLOYEE CODE] = EMPLOYEE_CODE
  ,[MAERSKID]     = MSKID
  ,[FULL NAME]    = CONCAT(FIRST_NAME,' ',SECOND_NAME,' ',THIRD_NAME) 
  ,[LOCATION]     = LM.LOCATION_NAME
  ,[COMPANY]      = CM.COMPANY_NAME
  ,[DEPARTMENT]   = DEPT.ACTIVITY_NAME 
  ,[LEVEL]        = LVL.LEVEL_NAME
  ,[CARD NO]      = CARD_NUMBER
FROM smart2uat.dbo.EMPLOYEE_MAST EMP 
LEFT JOIN smart2uat.dbo.ACTIVITY_MAST DEPT
  ON DEPT.ACTIVITY_CODE = EMP.ACTIVITY_CODE 
LEFT JOIN smart2uat.dbo.LEVEL_MAST LVL
  ON LVL.LEVEL_CODE = EMP.LEVEL_CODE 
LEFT JOIN smart2uat.dbo.LOCATION_MAST LM
  ON LM.LOCATION_CODE = EMP.LOCATION_CODE 
LEFT JOIN smart2uat.dbo.COMPANY_MAST CM
  ON CM.COMPANY_CODE = EMP.COMPANY_CODE;
```

Comment: Null records in which table? Change the Outer Join from Left to Right and then to Full and see if it helps?

Comment: @lad2025 Hi dude....Thanks for your response..I am not getting exact no. of records..old code giving around 7000 rows while new 4000

Comment: Hi man....@lad2025...thanks a lot for your response..ur code is working supe fine.......

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of those commas in the FROM clause. Try this instead for your FROM clause

```
    from
     smart2uat.dbo.ACTIVITY_MAST DEPT
     right outer join  smart2uat.dbo.EMPLOYEE_MAST EMP  
       on DEPT.ACTIVITY_CODE = EMP.ACTIVITY_CODE
     right outer join smart2uat.dbo.LEVEL_MAST LVL  
       on LVL.LEVEL_CODE =  EMP.LEVEL_CODE
     right outer join smart2uat.dbo.LOCATION_MAST LM  
       on LM.LOCATION_CODE = EMP.LOCATION_CODE 
     right outer join smart2uat.dbo.COMPANY_MAST CM 
      on CM.COMPANY_CODE = EMP.COMPANY_CODE
```